# Подключение шрифтов. Анонимайзер

Tags: html, css, google-fonts, шрифты

Всем привет, подключил шрифт 4 форматов на сайте perfectpic.ru, все работает,
Но если захожу с анонимайзера http://cameleo.xyz/ то пишет следующие ошибки:
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://obsxeztfmn2ha2ldfzzhk.cmle.ru/Roboto-Regular.ttf
(index):1 OTS parsing error: GDEF: misaligned table
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://obsxeztfmn2ha2ldfzzhk.cmle.ru/Roboto-Regular.woff
(index):1 OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>TOPIK</title>
 <style> 
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
  src: url('Roboto-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('Roboto-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('Roboto-Regular.eot') format('eot'),
  url('Roboto-Regular.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
 body{
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular' !important;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <p> Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Залетают буквенных, которое от всех, журчит скатился использовало речью пояс заголовок вдали дороге маленькая снова имени курсивных собрал ведущими своего? Меня!</p>
 <div class="font">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Подпоясал переулка точках рот над курсивных приставка ручеек, себя силуэт, агенство подзаголовок злых даже, повстречался предупредила от всех, родного правилами речью.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Такая же ситуация с font-awesome
Прогонял через www.font2web.com и все равно не работает . Как можно решить проблему

Comment: Не получается воспроизвести. Страница открывается через анонимайзер. Стиль применяется. Тянет ttf. Сохраненный ttf открывается в винде. Браузер firefox